# MultiProcess function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, process-pool

I'm diving into the multiprocessing world in python.

After watching some videos I came up with a question due to the nature of my function.

This function takes 4 arguments:

1. The 1st argument is a file to be read, hence, this is a list of files to read.
2. The following 2 arguments are two different dictionaries.
3. The last argument is an optional argument "debug_mode" which is needed to be set to "True"

```
# process_data(file, signals_dict, parameter_dict, debug_mode=False)
file_list = [...]
t1 = time.time()
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process_data, file_list)
t2 = time.time()
```

The question is:
How can I specify the remaining parameters to the function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With easy examples like this, why not post something we can just copy and run?

Comment: The function I have it's quite long. In principle, what I'm interested is how to set up the function with parameters in order to use the executor.map.

Comment: Right. So you write a very small test program. Your worker could be `def worker(a,b,c,d): print(os.getpid(), a, b, c, d)`. The problem you are interested in - how to map a function with multiple parameters - is a dozen lines.

Comment: Is any other way to achieve the goal besides ProcessPoolExecutor.map ?

Comment: `map` seems like the tool for the job to me. If the dictionary is large there may be a performance issue getting it to the child (on windows there is a copy, on linux you may be able to leverage copy-on-write view of parent memory space by placing the dict in a global variable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ProcessPoolExecutor.map` documentation is weak. The worker accepts a single parameter. If your target has a different call signature, you need to write an intermediate worker that is passed a container and knows how to expand that into the paramter list. The documention also fails to make it clear that you need to wait for the job to complete before closing the pool. If you start the jobs and exit the pool context `with` clause, the pool is terminated.

```
import concurrent.futures
import os

def process_data(a,b,c,d):
    print(os.getpid(), a, b, c, d)
    return a

def _process_data_worker(p):
    return process_data(*p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list = [["fooa", "foob", "fooc", "food"],
        ["bara", "barb", "barc", "bard"]]

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(_process_data_worker, file_list)

for result in results:
    print('result', result)
```

Comment: Did anything print? It works for me on Ubuntu. its very basic, should work everywhere.

Comment: I tested it on jupyter. I'll try later on pycharm. I'm a windows user btw.

Comment: Interesting. It would be worth adding the envionrment (jupyter on windows) to the question. Multiprocessing doesn't tend to work in interactive shells, especially on windows where modules need to be reimported in the child. I don't know about jupyter specifically but searching "multiprocesssing in jupyter windows" has a lot of hits.  One hit said that it works if you have the MP stuff in an imported module, not the main script.

Comment: I tried Jupiter but I'm developing in Pycharm :)
I'll give it a try later. I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list of lists containing parameters for each process:

```py
params_list = [[file1, dict1_1, dict2_1, True],
               [file2, dict1_2, dict2_2, True],
               [file3, dict1_3, dict2_3]]
```

Then, you can create processes like this:

```py
executor.map(process_data, params_list)
```

Comment: That's not quite all. Its not well documented, but the target function takes a single argument. If `process_data` takes 4, you need an intermediate function that unpacks them for you. Also, if you don't wait for `map` to complete but just exit the `with` clause, the work will be cancelled. `result = executor.map(process_data_caller, params_list)` is better.

Comment: I put in the executor.map only one parameter of the function even though it takes four because the examples I've looked at are like so.
Could you explain what the intermediate function means, and how to achieve the unpacking you suggested?